# Activate the frontmost Safari and run Javascript

Tags: macos, process, applescript

I'm trying to run Javascript on the Safari, whose frontmost is true.

```
tell (application "Safari" whose frontmost is true) to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
```

But I get an error like this:

```
execution error: Can’t get application "System Events" whose frontmost of it = true. Access not allowed. (-1723)
```

where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppleScript often requires the syntax be formatted in a specific way. In the case of your script it can't differentiate identifiers because you've placed them incorrectly on the same line.

```
set theScript to "alert('Hello, World!');"

tell application "Safari"
    set frontmost to true
    activate
    do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
end tell
```

You can test your script in AppleScript editor by compiling and running it. The `events`, `replies` and `results` should give you some indication of where problems might be.

**EDIT**: to deal with a process which is the frontmost (or most recent):*

```
set theApp to "Safari"
set theScript to "alert('Hello, World!');"

on isOpen(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end isOpen

set isActive to isOpen(theApp)
if isActive then
    tell application "System Events" to tell (process "Safari" whose frontmost is true)
        tell application "Safari"
            activate
            tell application "System Events" to set frontSafari to item 1 of (get name of processes whose frontmost is true)
            if (count windows) is 0 then
                display dialog "There are no " & theApp & " windows open." buttons {"OK"}
            else if frontSafari is "Safari" then
                tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
else
    display dialog theApp & " is not currently running." buttons {"OK"}
end if
```

Comment: This works. But if there are many Safari running (with different process ids, note here its not different windows) and say I have only one safari in the frontmost as true, then this script takes other safari, not the one whose frontmost is true

Comment: You should have pointed that out when you originally asked your question. It's easy to change the script to deal with it's processes - see the edit.

Comment: Its working on your machine? Because it runs the script in wrong safari again :(

Comment: Are you trying to get the top current process of Safari or the last Safari window accessed? It would probably help if you could explain a bit more of what you're looking to do here.

Comment: I'm trying to do this. Since many Safari are running. I will give one of the safari pid to the script, which will make it frontmost true. This is done in AS, and it works good. Now I want to access this Safari ( whose front most is true ) and run Javascript for this particular safari and not on other safari's.

Comment: The example I've posted should give you more than enough of an idea how to accomplish that.